# Draw on Canvas with Scala.js

Tags: scala, html5-canvas, scala.js

I'd like to draw on a [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) using [Scala.js](https://www.scala-js.org/).

On the server side, I've created a simple page with a canvas:

```
import scalatags.Text.all._

html(
  body(
    div(
      h3("Let's draw something ️"),
      canvas("canvas-id")
    )
  )
)
```

Now, on the client side, I'd like the user to be able to draw on the canvas with their mouse.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client side, I get the canvas by its ID and draw on it when the user moves the mouse over it:

```
get[Canvas]("canvas-id").fold(
  errorMsg => logger.warn("Could not find canvas. Error is {}", errorMsg),
  canvas => drawOnCanvasWhenMouseMoved(canvas)
)
```

This is the `get` method that returns a typed element:

```
/**
  * Gets an element of type `T` by an `elementId`. Returns either the element if
  * found or an [[ErrorMsg]].
  */
def get[T: ClassTag](elementId: String): Either[ErrorMsg, T] = {
  val queryResult = document.querySelector(s"#$elementId")
  queryResult match {
    case elem: T => Right(elem)
    case other => Left(ErrorMsg(s"Element with ID $elementId is $other"))
  }
}
```

where `ErrorMsg` is a simple value class:

```
case class ErrorMsg(value: String) extends AnyVal {
  override def toString: String = value
}
```

I draw using the [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/canvas):

```
private def drawOnCanvasWhenMouseMoved(canvas: Canvas) = {
  getContext2D(canvas).fold(
    errorMsg => logger.warn("Couldn't get rendering context of canvas: {}. Error: {}", canvas, errorMsg),
    context => canvas.onmousemove = { e: MouseEvent => drawOnCanvas(e, context) }
  )

  def drawOnCanvas(e: MouseEvent, context: CanvasRenderingContext2D) = {
    val x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft
    val y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop

    context.fillStyle = "green"
    context.fillRect(x, y, 2, 2)
  }
}
```

Finally, to get the rendering context, I use `getContext`:

```
/** Returns either this [[Canvas]]' [[CanvasRenderingContext2D]] or
  * an [[ErrorMsg]] if that fails. */
private def getContext2D(canvas: Canvas): Either[ErrorMsg, CanvasRenderingContext2D] =
  if (canvas != null)
    canvas.getContext("2d") match {
      case context: CanvasRenderingContext2D => Right(context)
      case other => Left(ErrorMsg(s"getContext(2d) returned $other"))
    }
  else
    Left(ErrorMsg("Can't get rendering context of null canvas"))
```

Result:

[image: drawing as gif]

Comment: what will be in case of drawing line by mouse which needs two positions?

Comment: @MHJ: Have a look at the [interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) of `CanvasRenderingContext2D`.